# RecyclerView overdraws items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm facing a pretty odd issue with all the `RecyclerView` in my application. It's not the first time that I use `RecyclerView` but that's the first time it happens. I think the best way to explain this is with a photo:

[image]

The list is constantly updated so the notify methods are called often. The code is a bit too complicated to be posted but I'm sure that everything is called from the UI thread.

As requested here are the code and the layout.

Code:

```
public class PlayersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayersAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final List<GameInfo.Player> players;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PlayersAdapter(Context context, List<GameInfo.Player> players) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.players = players;
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return players.get(position).name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        GameInfo.Player player = players.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(player.name);
        holder.update(player);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
        if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
            onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        } else {
            holder.update((GameInfo.Player) payloads.get(0));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return players.size();
    }

    public void notifyItemChanged(GameInfo.Player player) {
        int pos = players.indexOf(player);
        if (pos != -1) {
            players.set(pos, player);
            notifyItemChanged(pos, player);
        }
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged(List<GameInfo.Player> players) {
        this.players.clear();
        this.players.addAll(players);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView name;
        final SuperTextView score;
        final ImageView status;

        ViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_item, parent, false));
            setIsRecyclable(false);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerItem_name);
            score = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerItem_score);
            status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerItem_status);
        }

        void update(GameInfo.Player player) {
            score.setHtml(R.string.score, player.score);

            switch (player.status) {
                case HOST:
                    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person_black_48dp);
                    break;
                case IDLE:
                    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_access_time_black_48dp);
                    break;
                case JUDGING:
                case JUDGE:
                    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_gavel_black_48dp);
                    break;
                case PLAYING:
                    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_hourglass_empty_black_48dp);
                    break;
                case WINNER:
                    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black_48dp);
                    break;
                case SPECTATOR:
                    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_red_eye_black_48dp);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `GameInfo.Player` class:

```
public static class Player {
        public final String name;
        public final int score;
        public final PlayerStatus status;

        public Player(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
            name = obj.getString("N");
            score = obj.getInt("sc");
            status = PlayerStatus.parse(obj.getString("st"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Player player = (Player) o;
            return name.equals(player.name);
        }
    }
```

Custom item layout (R.layout.player_item):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playerItem_status"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:alpha="0.54"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playerItem_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <com.gianlu.commonutils.SuperTextView
            android:id="@+id/playerItem_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**:
Removing the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads)` method fixes the issue only if I use `notifyItemChanged(pos, player)`, the issue remains with `notifyItemChanged(pos)`. Would be nice to know why it happens.

Comment: can you post some code of your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: share your custom layout from RecyclerView items

Comment: @NileshRathod I've updated the question

Comment: why you are using setHasStableIds(true); in Adapter constructor?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar #setHasStableIds(true) is used to "indicate whether each item in the data set can be represented with a unique identifier of type java.lang.Long." and my items can, so I used it.

Comment: why are you using onBindViewHolder with payload argument. You are already setting new value via `notifyItemChanged(GameInfo.Player player) ` 
can you remove this and look at the result?

Comment: @RahulKumar check the updated answer, it's working but in an odd manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by removing the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads)` method, using `notifyItemChanged(pos)` instead of `notifyItemChanged(pos, player)` and setting the `ViewHolder` recyclable with `setIsRecyclable(true)`. Thanks to @RahulKumar for the suggestion.